# When I run the following query I got an error how to use trunc date() function Sql Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

help me on mentioned code When I run the following query I got an error. Can Someone help me to solve this.

```
Select 
     R_NUMBER
    ,CATEGORY
    ,DONOR_OP
    ,to_char(to_date(datetime_Table,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM EDW_TRANSACTION_BASE 
WHERE circle_id = '116'
AND to_char(to_date(datetime_Table,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY') = TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
AND trunc(REPORT_DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

In my data date format is DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI: SS and system date is 2/22/2022

Error message:

> Not a valid month

how may I scheduled without changing date in oracle sql

Comment: Why do you convert twice just to compare dates in your first date condition? Simply TRUNC both and compare like you do with your second.

Comment: you are comparing a string (to_char....) with a date (trunc(sysdate-1)). do as the first comment said and it should be ok. And why do you store dates in string format? this is not a good idea, as you just found out with your sql

Comment: First things first - what is the **data type** of column `report_date`? If it's `date` (as it should be), then you shouldn't be using any calls to `to_date()` and `to_char()`. To find out the data type, **don't guess**; instead, run `describe edw_transaction_base` and see what it reports back. If `describe` doesn't work on your system, tell us that too - we can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing dates you don't need the TO_CHAR() here:

```
to_char(to_date(datetime_Table,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY') = TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
```

change it to :

```
TRUNC(to_date(datetime_Table,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) = TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
```

in the where clause. (your TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) will give you the date without time string and I suppose you want to trunc the results from the datetime_Table too since they have time string included and the matching will not work properly if you're loading full time strings, but it's up to your data, I leave this part to you)